# Python can't find pyobdc. Could the name of the Folder be the Problem?

Tags: python, windows

I am running **64-bit Windows 7**, **python 3.7**.
I used `pip install pyodbc` and it installed **pyodbc-4.0.28.dist-info** version in the following directory in my pc: **C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages.**

Since I got the following warning - `import pyodbc ImportError: DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found` - so I used the sys.path to find out whether the path to it was there or not and it was>

```
C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\idlelib
C:\Users\Propietario\Python Scripts
C:\xampp\htdocs\Python Scripts
C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip
C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs
C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib
C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37
**C:\Users\Propietario\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages**
```

As it can be seen the path to the directory is included in the PATH variable.

I'm wondering if the problem is the directory's name? it's not pyodbc, but **pyodbc-4.0.28.dist-info**

By the way, `pip uninstall pyodbc` had no problem finding it

*Uninstalling pyodbc-4.0.28:
  Would remove:
    c:\users\Owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-package
s\pyodbc-4.0.28.dist-info*
    c:\users\Owner\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-package
s\pyodbc.cp37-win_amd64.pyd
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled pyodbc-4.0.28*

Does anyone have any idea about it. What can I do to solve the problem
Thanks in adavance

Comment: Do you have more than one python version, or more than one python environment on your system , e.g. anaconda?

Comment: @ShpielMeister: I only have one version of python: python 3.7. I only downloaded python once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not you.   it failed for me too. on a mac.

so doing a little digging - it's an outstanding issue -

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/677

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/663

return **import**("pyodbc") ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

the solution is "I am also encountering the same problem with pyodbc 4.0.28 while with 4.0.27 everything works as intended." Tatu Leinonen copyrite

Comment: Were you able to reinstall pyodbc 4.0.27 again? Did it solve the problem? I'm not sure how to select the version? I tried this: `pip install pyodbc-4.0.27`, but it didn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

I did not face issue with python but with maven. My observation is:

Some time there are issues with Get-Item -Path command or SETX PATH in PowerShell. You could try to set path variable through this script (run as admin) and try.

```
$existingpath = $env:Path
$newpath = $existingpath + ';' + '<Your Path>'
[System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Path', $newpath, [System.EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine )
```

Comment: I've never worked with the PowerShell, so I googled the differences between cmd and PowerShell. Before I try your script - and by the way, thanks for sharing it with me - I want to let you know that all the above paths are already separated by a semicolon. Should I still run the script?

Comment: If you have checked from GUI (System Properties > Advanced > Environment Variables) then, no need to execute the PowerShell script again

Answer (score 0):

As a @ ShpielMeister said, **there's an issue with** pyodbc version 4.0.28, so I decided to go with **version 4.0.27** for now. 
So for those of you who are new to python and pyodbc like me, the following code is the way to get a specific version:

```
pip install pyodbc==4.0.27
```

This version works just fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I know that this is a super old question, but this is one of the first results that comes up on Google for this issue.
I ran "pip3 install pyodbc" and the Idle shell (3.11) couldn't import pyodbc.
I uninstalled pyodbc and then **ran command prompt as an administrator**, using the same command "pip3 install pyodbc" and then Idle was able to import.

I don't know enough about the inner workings of Windows to know *why* this worked, but I suspect that it has something to do with the "path" since that was the gist of the warning message that cmd gave me when I ran the command to update after my first (failed) install.

edit: pyodbc v4.0.39

Comment: It is not a good idea to run stuff as an administrator because "it didn't work". Running things as admin opens you up to security issues. You should understand how Python attempts to import stuff and why the specific package failed to be found.

Comment: Hi Guy! I agree that generally one shouldn't run as administrator. I'm reasonably certain that the root issue is whether Python is installed "for this user or for all users on this machine."
The pip install error message stated that the package couldn't be added to the path and that the package was installed in users-->roaming rather than in program files with the rest of Python. Running as administrator allowed the installation to occur in the correct directory.